# Voltage swing level of AC-coupled CML

Tags: digital-logic

Reading through OnSemi's application note [AND8173](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8173-D.PDF), I'm having a hard time understanding the voltage swing level of AC-coupled CML (Current Mode Logic).

It says VoutputH/L=Vterm+/-200mV which means there's 4mA flowing through RT1 and RT2. But how can there be a current through C1 and C2?

[image: Figure 7 from OnSemi appnote AND8173]

<sub>Image source: Figure 7 from [On Semiconductor application note AND8173](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8173-D.PDF)</sub>

Comment: Sam Gibson and I have added the missing application note link to your question and explained what CML means. The phrase "VoutputH/L" does not appear in the application note so you might want to edit your question. You can use the HMTL markup `<sub>...</sub>` to add subscripts into your equations to make them more readable. Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 1):

CML is used both DC signals and AC protocols that have no DC.

So consider the caps for  AC, Xc(f)= 0 Ohms, thus the current swing is determined by Rt.

> which means there's 4mA flowing through RT1 and RT2.

Since the differential switch supplies 16mA shared by the internal equal 50 Ohm loads, the current peak swing is 8 mA not 4.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, in that the AC coupled interface shown in the figure does not allow DC operation.  That is, you cannot send a constant 1 or a 0 (or a constant voltage) over that interface.

But when you're sending serial data or a clock, the voltage on the line is constantly changing.  Depending on the value of the capacitor and the signaling  rate (how fast the interface switches between a logic 1 and a logic 0), the capacitor appears as a short circuit, or nearly so.

Note that CML does not require the DC blocking, or AC coupling capacitor.  That is just to establish the DC reference at the receiver.

Here's a more typical CML implementation, from the Cypress app note AN1202

[image: DC Coupled CML Interface]

Note the lack of an AC coupling cap.

Comment: Sometimes the 50 ohm terminations are at receiver side, and no terminations on transmitter side. Early DVI and HDMI works like this, but later those allowed differential transmitter side termination to get higher bandwidth.

Comment: I don't want to downvote this because your statements about DC vs AC are correct, but I don't agree that the implementation in that image is "more typical" CML. Look across textbooks, input stage circuits of serdes ports, etc and the expected CML input termination is pullups to VT or VCC. A DC-coupled implementation would have pullups at both the transmitter and receiver. Your input termination would likely work for DC-coupling (although it modifies Vicm so you'd have to check your levels are good), but often CML receivers already have integrated input terms, so this could confuse newbies.

Comment: We can debate ad-nauseam what implementation is, or is not "more typical".  I don't want to get into a "how many angels can dance on the head of pin" discussion.

Comment: And further more on down votes, others may disagree but I don't down vote an answer unless I think there's something technically wrong with it.